# Comment upvote button design is broken in Mobile view

Tags: bug, design, comments, mobile-web

In Stack Overflow mobile view, this is how the comment upvote button is rendering:

[image]

I upvoted the first comment, and it's in blue. But I didn't touch the other two comments, and they're also in blue.

> Chrome for Android 78.0.3904.62 
>   Android 9

Comment: I've seen this as well (Also Chrome for Android), but inconsistently. It usually happened after I had trouble loading a page, so I thought it was a Chrome caching error, not a Stack Overflow one. But I've never tried hard to specifically recreate it.

Comment: I've removed the status-review tag from this post because the separate mobile-web interface no longer exists.